# Django: Show data from current user

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I'm having trouble displaying data from current user. It shows all the shifts that was given to other users also. I don't have any idea how to do this. Below is my code.

*models.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    pass_word = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Rostering(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    begin_time = models.TimeField(default="")
    end_time = models.TimeField(default="")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class RosteringUser(models.Model):
    rostering_user = models.ForeignKey(Rostering, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

*views.py*

```
def my_shift(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = RosteringUser.objects.all()
        if queryset:
            for obj in queryset:
                id = Rostering.objects.get(rosteringuser=obj.id)
                obj.id = id
            return render(request, 'my_shift.html', {'queryset': queryset})
```

*my_shift.html*

```
{% for obj in queryset %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ obj.user.user_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.id.name }}-{{ obj.id.begin_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.id.name }}-{{ obj.id.end_time }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try like this:

```
         if queryset:
            for obj in queryset:
                id = Rostering.objects.get(rosteringuser=obj.id)
                obj.id = id
                querysets = obj
            return render(request, 'my_shift.html', {'querysets': querysets})
```

And in templates:

```
{% for object in querysets %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ object.user.user_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.id.name }}-{{ object.id.begin_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.id.name }}-{{ object.id.end_time }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This might help, i'll try @Manoj Tolagekar

Comment: there was no error, but it doesn't show any data at all

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_shift(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        rost_id = RosteringUser.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values("rostering_user_id").first()
        if rost_id :
           data = Rostering.objects.get(id=rost_id['rostering_user_id'])
           return render(request, 'my_shift.html', {'queryset': data })
```

in template you can directly display logged in username `{{ request.user.first_name }}`